# angularJS routing templateUrl

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes

I'm trying to use routing in angularJS and I've been able to set most of it using w3schools as a tutorial. The problem is that w3schools doesn't provide example files for their external htm files. 
here's what I have
JavaScript:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ["ngRoute"]);

app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when("/", {
        templateUrl : "librarian.html"
    });
});

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope)
{

});
```

main HTML:

```
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="./library.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <p id = "loginScreen" >
            username: <input id = "userName" name = "userName" ng-model="name"><br>
            password: <input id= "password" name = "password" ng-model="password"><br>
            <input type = "button" value = "login" id = "loginButton" ng-click="login()">
            <a href="#librarian">librarian</a>
    </p>
<script type = "text/ng-template" id = "librarian.htm">
    <div>hello</div>
</script>
<div ng-view></div>
</body>

</html>
```

What do I need to do in librarian.html to get the page to switch to it (currently the URL changes, but all of the elements on the page remain the same)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in Angular 1.6 changed from #/myUrl to #!/myUrl

You should change your ref to

```
<a href="#!/librarian">librarian</a>
```

Comment: That didn't work. I'm actually using 1.4 as well since I just copied and pasted the import links from the w3schools website

Comment: Where your page librarian.html of you . Try create it and remove `<script type = "text/ng-template" id = "librarian.htm">
    <div>hello</div>
</script>`

Comment: removing that line of code didn't help (I had added it in after looking at the tutorialspoint example for this problem). My librarian.html is in the same directory as my main html file

Comment: @Alex5775 you should change in router `.when("/librarian"` instead `/`

Comment: I did that and the page still didn't change, although I can't believe I missed that obvious error

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/G5929ns2rr3VZeVOKIGG?p=info there is a link to that, although I pretty much had posted my whole code except the really small library.html

Comment: Strangely that didn't work on my computer, but it did work on plunker. Actually, I just checked and it works on firefox, but not chrome. Is there an internet browser setting that you know of that could fix that? Normally I'd just use firefox, but the graders for my class require it to work on chrome

Comment: sorry , first time i see it . You can try remove chrome and install again

Comment: I'm running it from an Apache server now and it is working on chrome. Thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 0):

Make this Change

```
 <a href="#!/librarian">librarian</a>
```

and Change this

```
.when("/librarian", {
        templateUrl : "librarian.html"
    });
```

and create a file in your project folder

```
librarian.html
```